# What is the lowest allowable circuit height in Australia?

Tags: altitude, australia

What is the lowest height an RPL holding pilot can conduct a circuit? I would like to practice very low circuits to work on my quick thinking.

Comment: That sounds like practising sticking your hand in the fire to work on your reflexes.

Comment: Yeah practice it at 6000ft and if you descend below that, consider yourself dead. Never practice using the ground. Frankly I think touch and go landings should be performed at FL150

Comment: Just remember, you can't beat the record for lowest flight -- you can only tie it.

Comment: I would suggest speak to an instructor about this sort of question...

Comment: I vote to close this as "primarily opinion-based". The answer from @RalphJ is very good, but I doubt you can find facts for this question.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the first sentence is a very clear question with an available answer that isn't opinion based. And I'm glad OP is asking instead of just going out and doing it!

Comment: @jklingler I'd say that Australia's aviation regulations count as facts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to sit down with an instructor, rather than an internet message board, if you are seriously considering such a proposition as this.  Hopefully the instructor can talk you into a little more use of careful, cautious, wise thinking instead of a focus on what you term as "quick thinking".

There is a place for thinking quickly in aviation, but there is a much more important place for thinking wisely and avoiding unnecessary risks.  "How low can I fly this" doesn't very well fit into the category of wise & prudent.

I say this having in my background flying at lower altitudes for longer periods of time than most civilian pilots have been trained for.  Low level navigation at 300' was common in my previous role, but it was NEVER something that you got sent out to figure out by yourself.  You were trained to do it, how to do it well, and what to avoid.  And before each flight, there was some fairly extensive preparation, so that as many "split second" decisions as possible could be made well ahead of time, rather than on the spur of the moment.

I've also done some amount of flying (also in the military) where patterns are flown at 500' AGL.  Again, not something that is self-taught.  The big differences involve a lot of changes to the sight-picture, since you are now looking at the runway from an unfamiliar angle.  Can it be learned?  Yes.  Are there things that you need to be taught by people who have more experience than you do?  Absolutely.  Trying to do this on your own is a fairly good recipe for disaster.

Sit down with an instructor and have this conversation... *Please* don't do something foolish based on an answer from an internet forum!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I just want to reiterate that you should absolutely follow the advice in [Ralph's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/23310/755). That is, learn to make good (wise, prudent) aeronautical decisions and talk to an actual instructor. Don't do risky things just to "practice quick thinking." That's how you end up dead.

Now, to actually answer the question regarding the lowest safe altitude, here's the regulation for Australia:

> The LSALT (Lowest Safe ALTitude) must be calculated using the following method:
>
> > a. where the highest obstacle is more than 360FT above the height determined for terrain, the LSALT must be 1,000FT above the highest obstacle; or
> >
> > b. where the highest obstacle is less than 360FT above the terrain, or there is no charted obstacle, the LSALT must be 1,360FT above the elevation determined for terrain; except that
> >
> > c. where the elevation of the highest terrain or obstacle in the tolerance area is not above 500FT, the LSALT must not be less than 1,500FT.

Source: [Aeronautical Information Publication Australia GEN 3.3 paragraph 4.5](https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/aip/current/aip/general.pdf)

So, in summary, the lowest safe altitude is 1,000 ft. above the highest obstacle, except that it must be not less than 1,360 ft. above the highest terrain and not less than 1,500 ft. above sea level.